# Would [urban-environment] be a useful tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

for questions like these ones:
[What is the effect of streetlights on plants?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1484/what-is-the-effect-of-streetlights-on-plants)
[Is it safe to grow food plants near the road?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/15/is-it-safe-to-grow-food-plants-near-the-road)

In fact, the "related questions" algorithm picked up the road question as the top match for streetlights. So perhaps my tag is redundant.

Actually, I wonder how it did that?

Comment: probably (plants + road) + (plants + street) ? That's how I'd have detected it in code. I would change the tag to [urban-agriculture] which I'd apply to a question about How do you make a seed-bomb?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure... on one hand, it *might* be useful to have [urban-environment](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urban-environment) to categorize questions with issues specific to cities and such, that people are trying to overcome/work around. On the other hand, I can also see it being used to tag just about any question because the asker lives in a city.

So perhaps we can wait and see if we collect a few more similar questions before tagging?

Btw, the reason why the related questions algorithm linked the two, is because once you strip out the filler words, you have "vegetable", "garden", "street", "plants" in common between the two. So that was probably sufficient enough (in the absence of any other related questions) to be picked up.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I live on the edge of a town of 700.  I'd have never thought to tag my streetlights question with [urban-environment](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urban-environment), although I can see your point.